# Delphi. How to get warnings list after second compilation

Tags: delphi, warnings, compiler-warnings

When I compile my project for the first time I have a list of warnings. But if I second time compile the same project, this list is empty.

How to make this list be full every time I compile the project?

The only solution I have found is close and reopen the project (or sometimes IDE).

Comment: Main menu -> Project -> Synatx Check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perform a **build** of the project, rather than a **compile**. Choose the *Build* option from the *Project* menu to perform a build. If you are using keyboard shortcuts, it is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to build rather than <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to compile.

When you perform a compile, only the out of date units are compiled, and only when a unit is compiled are warnings emitted. When you perform a build, the all units are compiled.

Based on your comments, you seem reluctant to use the build action. I don't agree with your reasoning, but if you want compile to act on all source files, then delete all your DCU files before compiling.

Another option, that I was not aware of until Abelisto suggested it in comments, is the *Syntax Check* action on the *Project* menu.

Comment: Ok, I understand it. But I turn on "Auto increment build number" in project settings. So I need to manually decrement build number after each build.

Comment: Well, that's tough. The Delphi build number handling in the IDE is something of a joke. Don't use it. It's hopeless. You need to write a build script so that you can produce repeatable builds.

Comment: You mean build script using FinalBuilder, for example. Or something like this?

Comment: That would be one example. Myself, I write my own tools. It's really not that hard though to come up with something basic that serves your needs.